# Bukkit - UUID to Player method?

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

So, I'm fairly new to the Bukkit API, and to be honest, the Java class I took last year didn't help me as much as it should have.
I'm going to refer to a post from StackExchange[URL][Bukkit - Using static variables causing problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37871036/5563110[/URL]) throughout this post.
The nice user who answered my question told me to use a HashMap, with the UUID of each pair of players for the keys and values. He said to not use Player variables, instead use their UUIDs.
My question is, how can I use methods on players by specifying their UUID? Is there some sort of UUID.toPlayer(UUID) method I could use?

Thanks in advance :D

--Noone has replied to this post on the Bukkit forums, that's why I'm here--

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop through all players on the server and try to match their UUID.

```java
 public Player getPlayerByUuid(UUID uuid) {
      for(Player p : getServer().getOnlinePlayers()) {
          if(p.getUniqueId().equals(uuid)
              return p;
          }
      }

 }
```

This was found [here](https://bukkit.org/threads/how-can-i-get-the-player-from-a-uuid.156704/).

This will loop through all players online and match UUID.

You could store them in a hashmap of type `UUID, Player` or string to store the players' names. Then access by,

```java
Player p = hashMap.get(uuid here (key) );
```

You'd probably add the players once they join and add to a hashmap.

```java
hashMap.put(UUID (key), Player (value) );
```

If you want to access UUID by player, just switch it around.

Comment: Apparently using a Player object causes memory leaks (if you're not careful), would this be better than just storing Player in the HashMap instead of their UUID?

Comment: @Kaelinator Although HashMaps may leak too. The method scans the online players to see if someone has that UUID and then returns that player which shouldn't really be vulnerable.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try both :D

Comment: No problem. If you've got more questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 3):

A much simpler method works like this

```
UUID myUUID = myPlayer.getUniqueID();
String configLine = myUUID.toString();
```

Then

```
Player newPlayer = Bukkit.getPlayer(myUUID);
```

Or

```
Player newPlayer = Bukkit.getPlayer(UUID.fromString(configLine));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Player p = Bukkit.getPlayer(uuid);`

[source](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/Bukkit.html#getPlayer(java.util.UUID))

You can use

```
UUID.fromString("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx")
```

or get it from `player.getUUID()`